# Two Versions of Diacritics on the word "Allāh" in two famous Qurʾān Muṣḥafs: which one is more correct in terms of the pronunciation of Allāh?

Tags: quran, arabic, quran-recitation, uloom-al-quran, tajweed

In the famous [King Fahd Complex](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/King_Fahd_Complex_for_the_Printing_of_the_Holy_Quran) Uthmānī Madīnah Muṣḥaf, Allāh is written with the following diacritics:

[image: Allāh in Uthmānī Script]

Source: https://read.quranexplorer.com/2/7/7/Usmani/Mishari-Rashid/Hide/Tajweed-OFF

In the Indo-Pāk Muṣḥaf, Allāh is written with the following diacritics:

[image: Allāh in Indo-Pāk Script]

Source: https://read.quranexplorer.com/2/7/7/IndoPak/Mishari-Rashid/Hide/Tajweed-OFF

In this question, I am only concerned with the difference between fatḥah (in the Uthmānī script) and superscript alif (in the Indo-Pāk script) on the lām. According to the Tajwīd rules of both scripts, the fatḥah and superscript alif are supposed to produce different elongations, the former is supposed to be shorter while the latter is supposed to be elongated. It seems that according to the Uthmānī script, the "la" is supposed to be kept short (as in Al-lah), while according to the Indo-Pak script, the "la" is supposed to be elongated (as in Al-laah).

My question is, according to Tajwīd rules, which version of diacritics is more correct in terms of the accurate pronunciation of the word Allāh?

And is there any reason why the potentially less correct version chose the diacritics of Allāh as they did? There must be some reasoning behind it, due to the painstaking amount of research, effort, artistry, and calligraphy involved in designing each word and letter in the Muṣḥaf. For instance, if one sees the work and years spent in writing the Madīnah Muṣḥaf ([here](https://youtu.be/sVrAI8hcqY0), and [here](https://youtu.be/gqrNrmVE_nc)), a potential error in the diacritics of Allāh has to be intentional and not mistaken. What could be the reason behind selecting them as they are? Is there any official explanation available?

Thank you and jazākAllāhu khairā for your guidance.

Comment: Both are meant to be identical in pronunciation, the latter is meant to be simpler. You should stick to the one whose rules you know.

Comment: There's no difference both words are actually the same only the caligraphies are different, The above linked duplicate is discussing a similar case.

Comment: Thank you for your input. I am not a speaker of Arabic, so would it be possible for someone to find if any information is provided on the diacritics in the Madīnah Muṣḥaf. Maybe some paper is written on the selection of diacritics in the Madīnah Muṣḥaf, or the writing of Madīnah Muṣḥaf. Maybe on the internet or on their website: https://qurancomplex.gov.sa/ . It would be very kind of them if somebody can share if such a document is available. JazākAllāhu khairā for your help.

Comment: The fatha in the Indo-Pakistani version is not Arabic standard. Maybe there's an Urdu influence?